# HidD_GetAttributes fails for Logitech B100 mouse

Tags: c++, winapi, hid

I have two HID compliant devices from logitech ( VendorID 0x046d == 1133 ) : the K120 keyboard ( ProductID 0xC31C == 49948 ) and the B100 mouse ( ProductID 0xc05a == 49242 )

I can successfully talk to the keyboard using the HID class support routines https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538865(v=vs.85).aspx

Although the control panel shows the mouse installs properly, and it certainly works as a mouse, every HID class routine returns failure.

This code shows HidD_GetAttributes working on the keyboard but not the mouse

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <setupapi.h>
#include <ddk/hidsdi.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // get info set for all present HIDs

    GUID HID_GUID;
    HidD_GetHidGuid( & HID_GUID );
    HDEVINFO DeviceInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevs(
                                 &HID_GUID,
                                 NULL,NULL,
                                 DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT);

    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA DeviceInfoData;
    DeviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);
    int DeviceIndex = 0;

    // loop over present HIDs
    while ( SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(
                DeviceInfoSet,
                NULL,
                &HID_GUID,
                DeviceIndex,
                &DeviceInfoData))
    {
        DeviceIndex++;


        //Get the details with null values to get the required size of the buffer
        PSP_INTERFACE_DEVICE_DETAIL_DATA deviceDetail;
        ULONG requiredSize = 0;
        SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail (DeviceInfoSet,
                                         &DeviceInfoData,
                                         NULL, //interfaceDetail,
                                         0, //interfaceDetailSize,
                                         &requiredSize,
                                         0); //infoData))

        //Allocate the buffer
        deviceDetail = (PSP_INTERFACE_DEVICE_DETAIL_DATA)malloc(requiredSize);
        deviceDetail->cbSize = sizeof(SP_INTERFACE_DEVICE_DETAIL_DATA);

        //Fill the buffer with the device details
        if (!SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail (DeviceInfoSet,
                                              &DeviceInfoData,
                                              deviceDetail,
                                              requiredSize,
                                              &requiredSize,
                                              NULL))
        {
            cout << "SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail failed";
            continue;
        }

        // open the HID handle
        string myPath = deviceDetail->DevicePath;
        HANDLE myHandle = CreateFile(myPath.c_str(),
                                     GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                                     FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                                     NULL,
                                     OPEN_EXISTING,
                                     FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                                     NULL);
        if( ! myHandle )
        {
            cout << "Create File failed";
            continue;
        }

        // get attributes of HID
        int myVendorID;
        int myProductID;
        _HIDD_ATTRIBUTES attributes;
        attributes.Size = sizeof( _HIDD_ATTRIBUTES );
        if( HidD_GetAttributes(
                    myHandle,
                    &attributes ) )
        {
            myVendorID = attributes.VendorID;
            myProductID = attributes.ProductID;
        }
        else
        {
            // failure
            myVendorID = -1;
            myProductID = -1;
        }

        // display logitech devices
        if( myPath.find("vid_046d") != -1 )
            cout << myPath.substr(0,30) << "... VID: " << myVendorID
                 << " PID " << myProductID << endl << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
\\?\hid#vid_046d&pid_c05a#7&be... VID: -1 PID -1

\\?\hid#vid_046d&pid_c31c&mi_0... VID: 1133 PID 49948

\\?\hid#vid_046d&pid_c31c&mi_0... VID: 1133 PID 49948

\\?\hid#vid_046d&pid_c31c&mi_0... VID: 1133 PID 49948

\\?\hid#vid_046d&pid_c31c&mi_0... VID: -1 PID -1
```

Why can I not access the mouse?

Comment: How did you create this project ? in Visual Studio ? Is this a win32-project ? I try to talk to my HID-Keyboard and need a starting point.

Answer (score -1):

I've been struggling with this for a few days. I believe this is related to [Windows opening mice and keyboards in exclusive mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/top-level-collections-opened-by-windows-for-system-use).

I found that several of my keyboards *appeared* to work, but only because they were exposing HID endpoints that weren't mouse/keyboard, in addition to the "real" descriptors.

You can confirm this by also grabbing the `SPDRP_DEVICEDESC` property using [`SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551967(v=vs.85).aspx). For my system, all the red herrings were HID compliant devices or System Controllers, and the failures were all HID compliant mouse or keyboard.

Try opening the file as mode 0 (instead of generic read/write). The functions then worked for me.